# Ошибка “unexpected EOF while parsing”

Tags: python

```
import sys
x = int(input())
y = int(sys.argv[2])
z = int(sys.argv[3])
x!=0
x = str('la')
y = str( x * y )
z == 0 or z == 1
if z == 1:
    print ('!')
    if z == 0:
        print ('.')
print ('Everybody sing a song:' + (x * y + z))
```

Вот такой текст программы. При запуске выдает такую ошибку

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\Examples\Task2.py", line 2, in <module>
    x = int(input())
  File "<string>", line 0
^
SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing
```

Подскажите,пожалуйста, как исправить.

Comment: `int(input())` намекает, что образец кода у вас Питон 3, а текст ошибки говорит, что вы на Питоне 2 запускаете (пустой ввод вызывает SyntaxError в `input()`. Должны получить ValueError -- пустая строка не является целым числом)

Comment: Для чего эта строчка - ``x!=0``? И эта - ``z == 0 or z == 1``?